# Trying to read Outlook Public folder items in a C# ASP.NET web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, public-folders

Below is the C# code in page behind of my ASP.NET website.
This code works fine (executes on button click) and brings back what it needs to bring back into a div on the page when I debug on my machine.

```
protected void btnVctn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Visible = true;
    btnCloseVactn.Visible = true;
    ExchangeService exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
    exchangeService.Url = new Uri("https://mymailserviceurl/ews/exchange.asmx");


    Folder myPublicFoldersRoot = Folder.Bind(exchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);
    string myPublicFolderPath = @"IT Services\ITServicesOutofOfficeCalendar";
    string[] folderPath = myPublicFolderPath.Split('\\');
    FolderId fId = myPublicFoldersRoot.Id;
    foreach (string subFolderName in folderPath)
    {
        fId = FindPublicFolder(exchangeService, fId, subFolderName);
        if (fId == null)
        {
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: Can't find public folder {0} " + myPublicFolderPath;

        }
    }

    Folder folderFound = Folder.Bind(exchangeService, fId);
    if (String.Compare(folderFound.FolderClass, "IPF.Appointment", StringComparison.Ordinal) != 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "ERROR: Public folder {0} is not a Calendar " + myPublicFolderPath;

    }

    CalendarFolder AK_Calendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(exchangeService, fId, BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

    FindItemsResults<Appointment> AK_appointments = AK_Calendar.FindAppointments(new CalendarView(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)));


    string rString = string.Empty;


    foreach (Appointment AK_appoint in AK_appointments)
    {

        rString += AK_appoint.Subject + "<br/> Start Date: " + AK_appoint.Start + "<br/>End Date: " + AK_appoint.End + "<br/>";
    }

    Label1.Text = rString;

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#dvWorkQueue';", true);
}


public static FolderId FindPublicFolder(ExchangeService myService, FolderId baseFolderId,string folderName)
{

    FolderView folderView = new FolderView(100, 0);
    folderView.OffsetBasePoint = OffsetBasePoint.Beginning;
    folderView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(FolderSchema.DisplayName, FolderSchema.Id);

    FindFoldersResults folderResults;
    do
    {
        folderResults = myService.FindFolders(baseFolderId, folderView);

        foreach (Folder folder in folderResults)
            if (String.Compare(folder.DisplayName, folderName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                return folder.Id;

        if (folderResults.NextPageOffset.HasValue)
            folderView.Offset = folderResults.NextPageOffset.Value;
    }
    while (folderResults.MoreAvailable);

    return null;
}
```

When I deployed the site on the production IIS server, although the aspx page loads, when I click on 'btnVctn' button it errors out saying

> In order to access a public folder, the effective caller must have a mailbox. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: > Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: In order to access a public folder, the effective caller must have a mailbox.
>
> Source Error: 
>   Line 47:         Folder myPublicFoldersRoot = Folder.Bind(exchangeService, WellKnownFolderName.PublicFoldersRoot);

This is the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>

<add name="Databasename" connectionString="Data Source=mysource;Initial Catalog=Data;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>

</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix this.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you have outlook installed and configured in your local system. When you do the deployment to the server probably it doesn't even have outlook installed.